# Is it bad form to determine critical numbers and relative extrema without defining a closed interval?

Tags: calculus

I have a problem to determine critical numbers and relative extrema for the function

$f(x) = 2x^3+3x^2-12x$

But the problem does not state a closed interval. Also, my book's definition for the first derivative test assumes "$f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$"; and the definition for the second derivative test assumes critical point $c$ of $f$ lies on the "open interval $(a,b)$", where $a < c <b$.

If the problem does not state an interval, is it okay to just ignore the interval before using either the first or second derivative test? Or should the interval of $f$ be $(-\infty,\infty)$ with the justification that $f$ is continuous and differentiable for all real numbers $x$?

Comment: For RELATIVE (or LOCAL) extrema, you only need the derivates. For ABSOLUTE (or GLOBAL) extrema the derivates are not sufficient.

Comment: To elaborate on @Peter's comment, you can of course find local extrema in a graph by looking at the derivative, but since $f$ is a cubic, when $x\to\infty$, we see that $f(x)\to\infty$ but also, as $x\to-\infty$, $f(x)\to-\infty$, so we can always find a lower or higher value of $f(x)$ by making $x$ lower or higher. In fact the local extrema of $f(x)$ are only true when $-3.5<x<2.5$. If you look at any $x$ outside of this interval, you'd have a new minimum/maximum. So it's not only bad form, it's actually not true either.

Comment: @Jam, since the problem does not state an interval, should I just make up an interval? Such as $[-10, 10]$? It does sound odd to find local extrema without defining locality.

Comment: Does the exercise ask for global (absolute) extrema ? They actually do not exist , if the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: No, just relative extrema.

Comment: Then, forget the intervals! Just detect the extrema using the first and second derivate.